# Drop down menus appear on different monitor and xrandr output looks very weird

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

I've encountered a strange bug recently. Whenever I open up these drop down menus (see image), the menu appears on my secondary monitor. It also happens for every right click context menu. This happens for every single program that has this style of menu.

[image: File Edit Selection ... Menu on VSCode]

I think it has something to do with my displays. It only started occurring after I swapped the ports that my monitors were plugged into. Here is the output of my `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5360 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected primary 3440x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00 + 144.00*  119.98   119.88    99.93    59.94    50.00
   1680x1050     59.88
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
   1024x768     119.99    99.97    75.03    70.07    60.00
   800x600      119.97    99.66    75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       59.94
   640x480      119.52    99.77    75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
USB-C-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  3440x1440 (0x1c2) 799.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  3440 start 3488 end 3520 total 3680 skew    0 clock 217.32KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1453 total 1510           clock 143.92Hz
```

The weird part about it is that my displays are plugged into `DP-2` and `DP-4`.

Rebooting fixes the issue, but it seems to come back when I turn off my monitors at night when I go to bed, and turn them back on in the morning.

What could be causing this?

Other important technical info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64
Window manager: i3-gaps - i3 version 4.19-46-g5bf25e27
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER
Graphics driver: Nvidia proprietary
Not using Wayland
```